# Facebook SDK 4.5.0 returning wrong user id in android

Tags: android, ios, facebook

In my App i am integrating facebook SDK 4.5.0. 
To fetch details of user I am using method 
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest

In user json response i am getting wrong user id.

### In case of IOS for same application and same user i get correct userId.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

This is my Code to fetch user details:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(com.facebook.AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    doLoginFb(user);
                }

            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Please pay attention to code formatting

Answer (score 1):

After V2.0API user id is "app-scoped" so the id can be different for same user on different apps.
You can refer to the [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids)  for more details. 

 It also says this :

> No matter what version they originally used to sign up for your app,
>   the ID will remain the same for people who have already logged into
>   your app. This change is backwards-compatible for anyone who has
>   logged into your app at any point in the past.
>       If you're not mapping IDs across apps, then no code changes should be required.

Comment: Thanx.. But my problem is, i am able to fetch required data by using id which i am getting from ios call and unable to fetch data by using id getting through android sdk call

Answer (score 0):

Get some public profile of user:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me",
            params,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("JSON",response.toString());
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                        //data.getString("id"),
                        //data.getString("name"),
                        //data.getString("email")
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks... But still getting same id and it is unable to fetch data from web.